# Data structure for linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

What is the best way to keep a list of items that is sortable and searchable? I want to have a list of medication-indications that I want to keep in order like this:

Medication            --------- Indication

lisinopril          --------- hypertension

amlodipine besylate --------- hypertension

amlodipine besylate  --------- coronary artery disease (cad)

carvedilol           --------- hypertension

ciprofloxacin        --------- skin and skin structure infections

ciprofloxacin        --------- bone and joint infections

No matter what order, amlodipine besylate HAS to match hypertension. I need to be able to sort alphabetically. Then I need to be able to get subsets. So I need to be able to pull the indications for say ciprofloxacin and lisinopril and then search to see if hypertension is in that resulting list.

How can I do this? I have it currently as two separate hash sets.

Comment: [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: A linked list is a terrible data structure for doing efficient searches and for keeping it sorted, there are better alternatives.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez The OP wrote *sortable* not *sorted*. Also, if I understood correctly, they need to store a mapping medication->indications.

Comment: @Kartik what’s more sortable that something that is sorted all the time? :p Also, I think we’re interpreting the question differently. In my understanding, he’s sorting using two criteria: med, indication. I hope OP clarifies this, it’s confusing because he talks about lists but is using a hash set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using TreeMap

- stores key-value pairs in sorted(ascending) order.
- You can access the value using key
- Key can be 'Medication'
- Value can be 'Indication'

Answer (score 2):

Although it's a *tree* not a list, a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) meets the requirements of being sorted, efficiently `O(log(n))` searchable and you can get [subsets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet(E,E)) out of it. It'll be better if you declare it as a [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html).

Comment: OP was already using a hash set, so I’m assuming he’s fine with not having dups. We don’t even know why he mentioned lists when a set was in use.

Answer (score 0):

[TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) is a sorted set of items:

> A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. The elements are
>   ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at
>   set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

For searching, filtering, mapping, subset creation etc. I recommend using the **Java Stream API**.

Answer (score 0):

The **SortedSet** interface provides functionalities to keep the elements sorted. And the **NavigableSet** interface provides functionalities to navigate through the **SortedSet**.

Since the [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) class implements **NavigableSet** interface, it has the functionalities of both - the NavigableSet as well as the **SortedSet**. The TreeSet uses a self-balancing binary search tree, more specifically a Red-Black tree.

The contains() method is used to check if a given element is present in a given TreeSet. If the element is found, it returns true, otherwise false.

Answer (score 0):

[Use B+ tree.](https://www.javatpoint.com/b-plus-tree)
It is default sorted and efficient searches.

Insertion however may need loops to keep it balanced.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone! After a bit of experimentation with each of the suggestions, I was able to determine that a TreeMap was indeed the best solution. Since the treeMap contains Key-Value pairs, the Key in both maps serves as the "link" to maintain the relationship. Just make sure that if you add or delete an item from one Map you have to do the same to the corresponding Key in the other map.